# Count users, not enough memory error

Tags: users, error, memory, count

Hi I have like 2000 users in my system. I would like to get a count of the active ones, so I did it like this:

```
{{craft.users.group('member').count()}}
```

but this returns the count with the limit of 100, so when I remove the limit

```
{{craft.users.group('member').limit(null).count()}}
```

I got this error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /Users/alex/git/website/craft/app/models/BaseModel.php on line 280
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.total()` instead of `.count()`

`.count()` will query the db and fetch all fields for all items relating to your criteria and then count them.

`.total()` only counts the number of items your criteria returns without all of their fields.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Luke's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14669/57), you might want to consider bumping your php.ini file's [memory_limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) to something higher than 128M, like 256M.